# Laravel pagination render() method not working correctly

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.4

I am doing CRUD  and want to show data using pagination.So far,I retrieved data from mysql but when i clicked next button the route do not work.Thanks in advance for helping.Below i am uploading my code:

Here is my controller index method

```
 public function index()
{
   $alldat=DB::select("SELECT a.id as id,a.`name`as name,b.name as catName,(case when a.status=1 then 'Available' else 'out of stock' end) as status FROM `subcategories` a,`categories` b where a.cat_id=b.id");

   $query="SELECT a.id as id,a.`name`as name,b.name as catName,(case when a.status=1 then 'Available' else 'out of stock' end) as status FROM `subcategories` a,`categories` b where a.cat_id=b.id";

    $alldata = new Paginator($alldat, 5, 1);

    return view('admin_theme.dynamic_files.subcategory.allSubCategory',compact('alldata'));
}
```

Here is my view blade file:

```
<div class="form-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>SubCategory Name</th>
                            <th>ParrentCategory Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @foreach($alldata as $data)
                            <tr class="success">
                                <td>{{$data->id}}</td>
                                <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$data->catName}}</td>
                                <td>{{$data->status}}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{route('subcategory.edit',$data->id)}}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
                                    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {!!$alldata-> render()!!}
                </div>
```

Please,Help anyone.Thanks in advance

Comment: what you get when dd($alldata) ..?

Comment: after dd give:Paginator {#207 ▼
  #hasMore: true
  #items: Collection {#221 ▼
    #items: array:5 [▼
      0 => {#208 ▶}
      1 => {#210 ▶}
      2 => {#211 ▶}
      3 => {#212 ▶}
      4 => {#213 ▶}
    ]
  }
  #perPage: 5
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "/"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}

Comment: here path is "/ ",  i think it should be resolve.any idea?

Comment: Raoul Dijksman check it please

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public function index()
{
    $alldata = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT a.id as id,a.`name`as name,b.name as catName,(case when a.status=1 then 'Available' else 'out of stock' end) as status FROM `subcategories` a,`categories` b where a.cat_id=b.id"));   

    $alldata = $alldata->paginate(5);

    // return code..
}
```

Comment: i tried but give:  (1/1) FatalThrowableError

Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: no..same error...  (1/1) FatalThrowableError

Call to a member function paginate() on array

Comment: please notice on my first comment...there is path "/ "..i need to like as host /routename/?page=2